# Get HTML element with its XPath and document.evaluate, Google Script

Tags: javascript, html

I asked a similar question but I think I found and answer, which doesn't seem to work.

I need to get an element with the XPath //*[@id="container"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/p inside the html in this page:
https://prestadores.pami.org.ar/result.php?c=6-2-1-1&beneficio=150384706806&parent=00&vm=2

I will use this in order to retrieve the info:

```
var path = '//*[@id="container"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/p';

document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

but since Google Script doesn't have anything like it, I will execute that code inside a dialog popup as an html added to the html of the page I want to parse, and retrieve the result like this:

code.gs

```
function getPadron(){
var padron = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://prestadores.pami.org.ar/result.php?c=6-2-1-1&beneficio=150384706806&parent=00&vm=2');
  var cartilla = padron.getContentText('UTF-8');
  var xpather = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("XPather").getRawContent();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(xpather+cartilla);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'title');
}
```

XPather.html (This one is glued to the main html as you can see above)

```
<button onclick="Pather()">Press me</button>
<script>
function Pather()
   var path = '//*[@id="container"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/p';

   var element = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
   google.script.run.Resultado(element);

</script>
```

At this point the element already should be something like `<p>21/04/1996</p>` as you can see by just writing that code in the google chrome console, but it doesn't retrieve anything.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but I dont know why.
For some reason, the final HTML file doesn't seem to like when I use var, so instead I hardcoded it like this:

```
<button onclick="Pather()">Press me</button>
<script>
function Pather(){
google.script.run.Resultado((document.evaluate('//*[@id="container"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/p', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue).innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

I also added the innerHTML to extract the value.